# - oo_ - a! - o _ o _ _ o _ a _ _ _!

Tags: cipher

While I understand that many words will fit the following, the final version should and will make sense once you get the right words. The text includes many familiar names.

Thanks for the patience.

[image]

Comment: Are the dashes a dash or a letter indicator? Or can you not say? :P

Comment: Letter indicator.

Comment: Gur qnfurf vaqvpngr pncvgnyf

Comment: Familiar names to whom? Is this an insider's puzzle?

Comment: Sorry I'm voting this close because 2 reasons: this is a kind of "guess what im thinking" and.. [tag:cipher]? The tag is probably misused here imo.

Comment: Yes, the 'cipher' tag isn't appropriate. A poorly applied tag is easily resolved, though. Including site-specific usernames is problematic, too, but also easily resolved. I don't agree that it is a "guess what I am thinking" puzzle; I was able to use logical reasoning to slowly work out the entire message. @DEEM, I hope you consider reworking this a little bit, instead of abandoning it. It is, in essence, a good puzzle, I think.

Comment: I removed the 'knowledge' tag that was added by someone to make it "ok" to base a puzzle around the names of site users, because the tag's description says it is for knowledge that can be obtained from **external sources**, such as Wikipedia, dictionaries, etc.

Comment: Is the capital I (eye) in the third row a typo?

Answer (score 7):

Here is my answer.

Thanks to @Glorfindel for laying the groundwork.

> Look Ma! No consonants!
> This is my two hundredth question, kind of
> To the smartest puzzle solvers of StackExchange
> Each wins hundreds of badges
> Tom, Stiv, Beastly Gerbil,
> Bass, Rand al'Thor, hexomino,
> jafe, Gareth McCaughan, Alconja
> and many more!
> Tip of my hat.

Comment: @DEEM - Although this puzzle was closed, it would be nice to have some feedback about the intended answer, so I can know how close I was to getting it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm getting somewhere, but not far enough yet. At least I've identified all names ...

> This is my pro puzzle___ question, _i__ o_
>
>  So the greatest(?) puzzle wonders of StackExchange
>  Each KING(?) puzzlers of _a__e_
>
>  Tom, Stiv, Beastly Gerbil,
>  Bass, Rand al'Thor, hexomino,
>  jafe, Gareth McCaughan, Alconja
>  all _a__ _o_e!
>  -i_ o_ __ *a*.

The difference between underscores and dashes:

> dashes represent upper case consonants, underscores lower case consonants.

Also, random rant: why on Earth is 'y' not a vowel in English?

Comment: It is "sometimes"

Comment: If that's right, the puzzle can't be solved by newcomers. It is partisan. There was a previous puzzle, where one of the clues was the icon of a regular contributor and that part of the answer was the username. But that contributer had changed their icon, making it even more impossible to solve.

Comment: You are right @Weather Vane. I did not think of that so I will vote to close this